# Reading the final name of a file downloaded using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt

When downloading a file using QNetworkAccessManager (Qt 4.5.2) is possible that the original URL redirects to a new one containing the real name of the file downloaded. How this file name can  be read?

The answer should be QUrl QNetworkReply::url () const as the documentation says that: 
Note that the URL may be different from that of the original request.

Unfortunately it returns the original URL and not the new one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to parse Content-Disposition header (`reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition")`) manually in order to get filename from it.

Comment: Yes, it works. Returns the name of the file as:
attachment; filename="afile.zip"

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try getting it from the response header via:

```
QNetworkRequest::header(QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader)
```

The documenation states that QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader:

> corresponds to the HTTP Location
>   header and contains a URL representing
>   the actual location of the data,
>   including the destination URL in case
>   of redirections.

[`QNetworkRequest::header` documentation](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qnetworkrequest.html#header).

[`QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader` documentation](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum).